IdentityUser is full of unnecessary properties
I'm using Identity in ASP.NET Core 8 and when setting up the ApplicationDbContext that inherits from IdentityDbContext, Identity requires my ApplicationUser to inherit from IdentityUser. The problem is that I don't want my ApplicationUser class to inherit all IndentityUser's properties as I don't need them. I don't need Password, LockoutEnabled, etc. because I'm using OAuth for authentication.
How can I set up an ApplicationUser class that is accepted by IdentityDbContext without inheriting any of IdentityUser's properties?
I have tried unmapping them but even then some still get mapped (See migration)
ApplicationUser.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public override string? NormalizedUserName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? Email { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? NormalizedEmail { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? PasswordHash { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? SecurityStamp { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public override int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    }
}

ApplicationDbContext.cs
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Project
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");

            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .ToTable("Users");

            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .ToTable("Roles");
        }
    }
}

Migration:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Project.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class Init : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Roles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Roles", x => x.Id);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Users",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ProfilePicture = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "tinyint(1)", nullable: false),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_Roles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "Roles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_Roles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "Roles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(255)", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "Roles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "Users",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "Users",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Roles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Users");
        }
    }
}


Does it matter? You don't have to use those properties. It isn't making your software slower or anything either.

I don't want them because then they will be added to the database schema creating clutter

Add [NotMapped] to them then.

Even when using the [NotMapped] attribute some properties still get mapped. I have update the question with the code.

Then why are you trying to use IdentityDbContext? If you want that much control, create your own user management.

Because even though I don't want the default properties I still want to be able to take advantage of UserManager and RoleManager

I have solved the problem using the fluent API
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Ignore(u => u.EmailConfirmed)
        .Ignore(u => u.AccessFailedCount)
        .Ignore(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp)
        .Ignore(u => u.Email)
        .Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnabled)
        .Ignore(u => u.LockoutEnd)
        .Ignore(u => u.NormalizedEmail)
        .Ignore(u => u.NormalizedUserName)
        .Ignore(u => u.PasswordHash)
        .Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumber)
        .Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        .Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
}


Consider using bounded contexts when it comes to IdentityDbContext. For instance have an AuthenticationDbContext which extends IdentityDbContext which is injected and referenced for all Auth-related code, and an ApplicationDbContext extending DbContext.
In the ApplicationDbContext you don't need a full User entity with Claims, Roles, etc. exposed, you can use a simplified User entity that only exposes the fields from the AspNetUser table that you need in your application. This also helps prevent accidentally exposing the full authentication structure, (if you serialize a User) and makes the user information more suited to what application code needs from a user.

I agree it might be a better approach but won't having a separate DbContext for authentication still be bloated with all the default IdentityUser properties?
